# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Tags: python, list, numpy

I was trying to convert a list to array with this code:

```
[t.numpy() for t in super_final_predictions]
```

But, An Unexpected error occurs

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'numpy'

If anyone could help me it would be greatful.

Comment: What is `super_final_predictions`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to convert the list `t` to an array, you can just say
`t_array = np.array(t)`

Answer (score 0):

try this way to convert list to numpy array

```py
import numpy as np

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr = np.array(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert lists to Numpy arrays, you should be using the following syntax

```
[numpy.array(t) for t in super_final_predictions]
```

Please note that this answer that I'm giving assumes that super_final_predictions contains multiple lists and the output you want is a list of numpy arrays.

If you want to convert the entire super_final_predictions list to a n-dimensional numpy array, you should be using

```
numpy.array(super_final_predictions)
```

Also, specify the datatypes while creating the array as it may be important for your use case.
For instance :

```
numpy.array(super_final_predictions , dtype = np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[np.array(t) for t in super_final_predictions]
```

Or just simply:

```
np.array(super_final_predictions)
```

The second code would convert the whole nested list to an array, which should be what you want.

Comment: Thank you for response,
But, Unfortunately an unexpected error occurs: [link](https://i.imgur.com/Th9mhKk.png)